# Configuring email for a development machine

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, sendmail

Almost every article I have found on this subject, including those on 'ask ubunutu', go along the lines of "follow this (deadlink to an article) BUT modify this that and the other". Regardless to say, I can't get things to work.

Would somebody please be kind enough to outline all the steps required to setup postfix or sendmail, to work alongside a php development environment. I want to be able to send an email from my php scripts, to ANY address, BUT, have them all stored locally in Maildir format.

From there, I would like to be able to configure a client like Thunderbird or Evolution, to display those emails.